# HightCharts Scatter :How to cancel automatically selected node

Tags: highcharts

update 'Highcharts' Version

When I move the mouse to automatically select a node within 'Highchart' area

How to cancel automatically selected node?

I want when the mouse is moved to the node re-start event not moved to 'Highcharts' area .

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo.

Answer (score -1):

At this lines:

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
      stickyTracking: false
   }
}
```

set the `plotOptions.series.stickyTracking` attribute `false`